# For comprehension Try monad with unhandled Exception

Tags: scala, error-handling, try-catch, for-comprehension

I am trying to learn how to use Try with for comprehensions in scala.

In the below sample code(**result1**),

if the last statement in for comprehension throws an unhandled exception,
Code doesn't break and an Try[Int] is returned.

But, if the sequence of statements is changed in for comprehension (**result2**). A runtime exception is thrown.

```
package simpleTryExample

import scala.util.Try


object SimpleTryExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val result1 = for {
      a <- strToInt("3")
      b <- strToInt("a")
    } yield (a + b)

    println("result1 is " + result1)

    val result2 = for {
      a <- strToInt("a")
      b <- strToInt("3")
    } yield (a + b)

    println("result2 is " + result2)

  }

  def strToInt(s: String): Try[Int] = {
    s match {
      case "a" =>
        println("input is a")
        throw new RuntimeException("a not allowed")
      case _ => println("other then a")
    }
    Try(s.toInt)
  }
}
```

Output :-

```
other then a
input is a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: a not allowed
    at simpleTryExample.SimpleTryExample$.strToInt(SimpleTryExample.scala:30)
    at simpleTryExample.SimpleTryExample$.main(SimpleTryExample.scala:18)
    at simpleTryExample.SimpleTryExample.main(SimpleTryExample.scala)
result1 is Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: a not allowed)
input is a
```

I was expecting result2 to be a Try[Int] type.
What i am doing wrong here ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your second example, you're throwing the exception before entering the `Try[T]` context.

In your first example, when running `strToInt("a")`, you're already in the context of a `Try[T]`, since the code is desugered to:

```
strToInt("3").flatMap(_ => strToInt("a"))
```

Since the first invocation of `strToInt` is successful, everything executed after it inside the for comprehension is in the context of a `Try`. But, in the second example, we have the opposite:

```
strToInt("a").flatMap(_ => strToInt("3"))
```

`strToInt("a")` will throw a `RuntimeException` since we're *still not* in a `Try` context, it is only applied when you try to parse `s` to an `Int`.

To avoid this altogether, move the try higher up before the pattern match:

```
def strToInt(s: String): Try[Int] = {
  Try {
    s match {
      case "a" =>
        println("input is a")
        throw new RuntimeException("a not allowed")
      case _ => println("other then a")
    }
    s.toInt
  }
}
```

And now we get:

```
other then a
input is a
result1 is Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: a not allowed)
input is a
result2 is Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: a not allowed)
```